# How to handle an action correctly with redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I am using redux-saga in my project with react. One of my sagas looks like this:

```
    function* deleteCitySaga(payload) {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + loadState(),
      Accept: 'application/json'
    }
  };
  const data = yield axios.delete(routeDeleteCiudad + payload.id, config)
    .then(response => response)
    .catch(err => err.response);
  }
```

What I want to do is to see my action as a promise, so I can know when the request made from saga is finished. This is what the call to action looks like from my component:

```
    handleEliminar = () => {

     this.props.handleDelete(this.state.id)
     .then((success)=>{console.log('End')})//This is what I want to do, I want to know when my action ends
     .catch((error)=>alertError);
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
     handleDelete: bindActionCreators(deleteCity, dispatch),
      });
```

what would be the best way to do what I need?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Redux-saga works only with plain action objects. You can let the component know about the finished loading by changing redux state or you can pass a callback function as a property of the action object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux saga doesn't really have an easy way to do that. Most commonly, you'll fire off an action and then forget about it. If you do care about the results of that action, you can have the saga make some change to the redux store, and that state change is what alerts you to the fact that it's done.

I can think of one way to do it: When dispatching the action, you'll need to create a new promise, and pass the resolve and reject functions as part of the action. The saga will then do what it does and call resolve or reject once its done. For example:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  handleDelete: (id) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'deleteCity', id, resolve, reject });
  });
})

function* deleteCitySaga(action) {
  try {
    // some code omitted
    const response = yield axios.delete(routeDeleteCiudad + action.id, config);
    action.resolve(response);
  } catch (err) {
    action.reject(err);
  }
}
```